# FormCalc Date function Adobe LiveCycle

Tags: adobe, livecycle, livecycle-designer

I have two fields (1) start date and (2) end date in a PDF form.  I would like a message to appear if the user selects a date that is not between specific dates. For instance, if a user does not select a date that is ">01/01/2014 AND <01/01/2015" I have tried the following code but with no success.  I'm using 'FormCalc' on the 'Exit' event.

```
var selectedNum = Date2Num($.rawValue, "YYYY-MM-DD")
    if ( selectedNum >01/01/2014AND<01/01/2015) then
    xfa.host.messageBox("Please enter a date for 2014.")
    xfa.host.setFocus("DateTimeField1")

endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code.

```
 var selectedNum = Date2Num($.rawValue, "YYYY-MM-DD")
 if (  (selectedNum<41639)OR (selectedNum>42004)) then
    xfa.host.messageBox("Please enter a date for 2014.")
    xfa.host.setFocus("DateTimeField1")
 endif
```

Date2Num function according to documentation [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/es/FormCalc.pdf).

> Returns the number of days since the epoch, given a
>   date string.

that means that in comparison you should also use numbers.

- 41639 represents 01/01/2014
- 42004 represents 01/01/2015

Comment: This code worked out well.  Thank you for supplying the syntax and for pointing me towards the documentation.